# Capital E not working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I recently updated some visual studio extensions and have noticed that I cannot type uppercase E on my keyboard in Visual Studio for some reason. Every other uppercase character types correctly. I am able to type uppercase E in every other application apart from Visual Studio.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you type a lowercase e?  Maybe try another keyboard...

Comment: Yes, I can type in a lowercase e but not uppercase E. Tried about 4 different keyboards and on all the uppercase E works in every other application apart from Visual Studio!!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have been caused by the PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio extension. See the [Shift + E bug discussion](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597/view/Discussions/1). Apparently, there's an update available as of August 11th but you can also search for and remove the `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.PowerShell.ExecuteAsScript` key binding in the Visual Studio options.

It's quite tricky to find this problem as you typing "Shift + E" in the key-mapping options dialog doesn't show associated commands.